# One folder that can be accessed by multiple sites

Tags: iis-7

Working in IIS7x and a handful of MVC3 sites. I'm trying to make the contents single folder (.wvm files) accessible to a number of different websites (each resolving to a different domain).

How do I configure the server so that links resolve to a physical path on the server's drive instead of a relative path within a given site's folder structure?

e.g. the same physical file should serve both these requests

```
http://www.mySite1.com/media/aCommonVideo.wmv
http://www.myOtherSite.com/media/aCommonVideo.wmv
```

thx

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for Virtual Directories. [See here.](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory)

Comment: beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a virutal folder in each of those descrete IIS sites called "Media" that points to the same physical folder.